# Iterating Through Each Checked Input Affecting Unchecked Inputs

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list of check boxes inside p elements

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <p><input name="product" type="checkbox"> Unchecked </p>
    <p><input name="product" type="checkbox"> Unchecked </p>
    <p><input name="product" type="checkbox"> Unchecked </p>
    <p><input name="product" type="checkbox"> Unchecked </p>
    <p><input name="product" type="checkbox"> Unchecked </p>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
</div>
```

But If I check the 3rd check box for example it affects the 1st and 2nd

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    $('#wrapper p').each(function() {
        if ($('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')){
            $(this).text($(this).text().replace("Unchecked", "Checked"));
        }
    });
});
```

I think it's because it is going through all the previous check marks once it finds one that is checked but I am not sure how to fix this.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pt9w8ksf/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input tags are descendants of your paragraphs so you have to traverse down the DOM tree. You have to use `this` and then find the nearest checkbox.

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    $('#wrapper p').each(function() {
        if ($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')){
            $(this).text($(this).text().replace("Unchecked", "Checked"));
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pt9w8ksf/3/

Answer (score 1):

You were very close:

http://jsfiddle.net/23xwhh3b/

You just needed to add `, this` to the following statement, like so:

`if ($('input[type=checkbox], this).is(':checked')){`

The jQuery selector can take a **second parameter** which specifies the **context** the first parameter (the selector) should be constrained to.

In this case, we want the `input[type=checkbox]` selector constrained to the current context (that is, the currently processed `p` in the `each()` function).

We can refer to the current function context using `this`.

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
  $('#wrapper p').each(function() {
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]',this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace("Unchecked", "Checked"));
    }
  });
});
```